# How to convert special ASCII characters to hex in Perl

Tags: perl

I have written a serial port program in Perl. Reading the output on STDOUT( screen), I get output as the special ASCII characters: `:- Black smiley white heart`. How do I convert them back to hex format?

Comment: Ahhh I know the ans.... $var1 = ("H*",$ASCII );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [perldoc -f ord](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ord.html).